# How to tell CMake to use Windows paths, not Cygwin ones?

Tags: cmake, cygwin

I am on Cygwin and I would like to call a compiler installed on Windows. I have an issue with the paths format.

With this very simple `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR Cortex-M4)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER iccarm.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER iccarm.exe)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER iasmarm.exe)

project("test" C)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

if(NOT EXISTS main.c)
    file(WRITE main.c "int main(void){return 0;}\n")
endif()

add_executable(
    test
    main.c
)
```

I get an issue when CMake checks for the compiler:

```
-- The C compiler identification is IAR
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded
  Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/nobody/home/sandbox/cmakeiar/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

It is because CMake doesn't know, or perhaps it should know, that `iccarm.exe` is a Windows program that is expecting windows paths.

Is there a solution to give CMake this information?

I imaging something like:

```
if(PLATFORM_IS_CYGWIN)
    set(CMAKE_IS_WINDOWS_EXECUTABLE iccarm.exe)
endif()
```

Comment: Which version of CMake do you use? Cygwin's CMake package or Windows installed CMake? The first would give prefixes, the second won't.

Comment: I use the Cygwin version, and I tried both

Comment: Strange, I've checked the code again: the only thing I see in the platform check is if `__CYGWIN__` definition is there. Could you please run `cmake.exe --system-information` and add all variable entries that have `CYGWIN` in its name or value? Something like `_PLATFORM_DEFINES` would be especially of interest. You could also try to give full paths to the compiler in Windows format.

Comment: The problem is not the full paths to the compiler, but the path given as arguments to the compiler. As CMake does the compiler check internally I cannot access to the temporary path and files it generates. Of course if CMake tries to do `iccarm -c /cygdrive/c/...` it won't work. CMake has to give Windows paths such as `iccarm -c C:\...`.

Comment: @Florian I ran `cmake --system-information` and got a lot of CYGWIN there. What information are looking for ?

Comment: I've checked again with the IAR compilers and it does work when using the Windows's CMake version (in my case version 3.9.0). Please find the details in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

Please be aware that Cygwin's CMake would give `/cygdrive` prefixes, but Windows installed CMake version won't.

I've run a test with your `CMakeLists.txt`, the IAR ARM compilers in my `PATH` environment and could successfully run from the Cygwin bash shell:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/CMake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is IAR
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...
```

If I do just call `cmake ..` (the Cygwin version) I get the same errors you got.